# On click of the button shift the sidebar to inside from screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, sidebar

I have some content on left and the sidebar on the right. On click of the cross button of the sidebar I want to translate away the sidebar to the right until it's off the screen

```js
$(".open-file-sidenav").click(function(){
    $(".files-sidenav-wrap").addClass("file-sidenav-slidein");
    $(".files-sidenav-wrap").removeClass("file-sidenav-slideout");
    $(".feed-post").addClass("content-on-files-sidenav-open");
    $(".feed-post").removeClass("content-on-files-sidenav-closed");
    $(".files-sidenav-wrap").css("display", "block");
    // .content-on-files-sidenav-open
});
$(".close-files-sidebar-btn").click(function(){
    $(".files-sidenav-wrap").removeClass("file-sidenav-slidein");
    $(".files-sidenav-wrap").addClass("file-sidenav-slideout");
    $(".feed-post").removeClass("content-on-files-sidenav-open");
    $(".feed-post").addClass("content-on-files-sidenav-closed");
    $(".files-sidenav-wrap").css("display", "none");
});
```

```css
.content-on-files-sidenav-open {
  padding-right: 0px;
  max-height: calc(100% - 0px);
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.content-on-files-sidenav-closed {
  padding-right:0px;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.files-sidenav-wrap {
  width: 250px;
}

.file-sidenav-slideout {
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  max-height: calc(100% - 0px);
  transform: translateX(0px);
  width: 250px;
}

.main-content {
  display: flex;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="feed-post">
    <div class="some-conntent">
      <p>some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="files-sidenav-wrap">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <h5 class="mb-0 font-weight-bold">Attachments</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close close-files-sidebar-btn"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is the code i have added. this is the code i have added

Answer (score 0):

Add the number of pixels you want the element to move in the `translateX()` function

**OR**

If you want the element to slide the entire width of the device you can use:
`translate(100vw)`

**Before**

```
.file-sidenav-slideout {
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    max-height: calc(100% - 0px);
    transform: translateX(0px);
    width: 250px;
}
```

**After**

```
.file-sidenav-slideout {
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    max-height: calc(100% - 0px);
    transform: translateX(100vw);
    width: 250px;
}
```

To get a smooth transition you can add this line to your `files-sidenav-wrap` class:

```
transition: all ease-in-out .4s;
```

Comment: Also I want to expand the feed post content and with that i get scroll in body

Comment: I want some transition or animation too on click it should slide out smoothly

Answer (score 0):

```js
          
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $(".open-file-sidenav").click(function(){
              
                $(".files-sidenav-wrap").addClass("file-sidenav-slidein");
                $(".files-sidenav-wrap").removeClass("file-sidenav-slideout");
                $(".feed-post").addClass("content-on-files-sidenav-open");
                // .content-on-files-sidenav-open
            
            });
            $(".close-files-sidebar-btn").click(function(){
            
                $(".files-sidenav-wrap").removeClass("file-sidenav-slidein");
                $(".files-sidenav-wrap").addClass("file-sidenav-slideout");
                $(".feed-post").addClass("content-on-files-sidenav-closed");
            });
            });
```

```css
.content-on-files-sidenav-open{
        padding-right: 0px;
        max-height: calc(100% - 0px);
        transform: translateY(0px);
      }
      .content-on-files-sidenav-closed{
        padding-right: 250px;
        transform: translateY(0px);
      }
      .files-sidenav-wrap{
        width:250px;
      }
      .file-sidenav-slideout{
        height: 100%;
        margin-top: 0px;
        max-height: calc(100% - 0px);
        transform: translateX(100px);
        width: 250px;
      }
      .main-content{
      display:flex;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="main-content">
        <div class="feed-post">
          <div class="some-conntent">
            <p class="open-file-sidenav">some text</p>
          </div>
          <div class="files-sidenav-wrap">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <h5 class="mb-0 font-weight-bold">Attachments</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close-files-sidebar-btn close" ><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    <html>
```

first of all, you forget to put your jquery code inside document.ready and your transform 0 to 100 or any other number as you want.

Comment: no actually I want to remove the sidebar from the screen and exapand the feed post content @Udal Pal

Comment: what actually you want ?? give me your final requirement I will do it. @AISHWERYASINGH

Comment: I want to show and hide the sidebar on clik of cross icon and and button on view files vice versa . With some smoth translation